# Issue running OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, openssl, udp

I get the following error when I try to run the below code with openssl dependencies.

Link to Code: https://github.com/TimonPost/udp-dtls

Error:

```
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.72
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.72`

Caused by:
 process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wintun-main\target\debug\build\openssl-sys-4454fbdd0966bbd8\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
OPENSSL_DIR = C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wintun-main\OpenSSL-Win32
cargo:rustc-link-search=native=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wintun-main\OpenSSL-Win32\lib
cargo:include=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wintun-main\OpenSSL-Win32\include
cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/expando.c
OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
DEBUG = Some("true")
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\wintun-main\\OpenSSL-Win32\\include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-E" "build/expando.c"
exit code: 0
version: 3_0_2
cargo:rustc-cfg=osslconf="OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD"
cargo:conf=OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl300
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl101
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl102
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl102f
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl102h
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110f
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110g
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110h
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl111
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl111b
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl111c
cargo:version_number=30000020
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIBS
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIBS unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIBS
OPENSSL_LIBS unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_STATIC
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl102f
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl102h
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110f
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110g
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl110h
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl111
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl111b
cargo:rustc-cfg=ossl111c
cargo:version_number=30000020
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIBS
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIBS unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIBS
OPENSSL_LIBS unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_STATIC
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIBS
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_LIBS unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIBS
OPENSSL_LIBS unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_STATIC
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_OPENSSL_STATIC unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
OPENSSL_STATIC unset

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'OpenSSL libdir at `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wintun-main\OpenSSL-Win32\lib` does not contain the required files to either statically or dynamically link OpenSSL', C:\Users\Administrator\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\openssl-sys-0.9.72\build/main.rs:367:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I am not able to figure out what the issue is. I have installed openssl and mingw exe files and added paths to the environment variables as well as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cloned your repo and was able to build it after a few steps. Below is what I did.

- Install openssl for windows using the following link:

[Win64 full install for software developers](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-3_0_2.msi)

- Make sure the following environment variable is set:

`OPENSSL_DIR=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64`

- Update the openssl cargo crate version to `openssl = "0.10.38"`

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Now I get the following error: error: could not find native static library `ssl`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?. How do I resolve that?